# How to temporarily highlight stock ticker value changes using ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to make a simple stock ticker using ReactJS.  I would like to temporarily highlight value changes.  E.g. show the price colored red for 1 second if it decreases and green if it increases, then revert to black.  For example, see [www.google.co.uk/finance](https://www.google.co.uk/finance) when the markets are open.  What is a simple way to achieve this using ReactJS?

The code below updates the color after each price change, but the update is permanent not temporary.

```js
class StockTicker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {price: 1, lastPrice : 1};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      2000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      price:  Math.floor(Math.random() * 200+200), lastPrice: this.state.price 
    });
  }
  
  change() {
    if(this.state.price > this.state.lastPrice){
      return "green";
    }else  if(this.state.price < this.state.lastPrice){
      return "red";
    }else{
      return "black";
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
     
        <h2 className={this.change()}> {this.state.price}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(
  <StockTicker />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

It can be run in codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pNMLYN

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i dont think Reactjs is the thing here, looks like plain css to me :). Please share some code if you expect constructive answers ! :)